# How to display text on date tribute in case of null value or empty

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have a date attribute name"release" to display release date of product on product view page, I used below code which working fine, only required help is to display TBC (some text) in case if there is no value assign to attribute

```
<?php 
$source = $_product->getdata('release');
$date = new DateTime($source);
echo $date->format('d M Y'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$source = $_product->getdata('release');
if ($source) {
    $date = new DateTime($source);
    echo $date->format('d M Y'); 
} else {
    echo __('TBC');
}
```